# How to show multiple tooltips at once

Tags: qt

I my application I have user-filled form. I want to display error messages for every incorrectly filled field on submit. My first intention was to display a tooltip near every lineedit (QToolTip::showText), but I can't show multiple tooltips at once. It always only one tooltip is visible.

So is it possible to show multiple tooltips at the same time?

Comment: Tooltips in Qt can only be shown once at a time. You could circumvent this by writing your own tool tip implementation but it might be easier to rethink your design. Perhaps an embedded label, red borders for problematic fields, a warning icon that appears next to the field with an appropriate tool tip, some combination of all of the above, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I had quickly browse through qtooltip sources. It is definitely not possible to create multiple tooltips as it is used in singleton manner.

I will do as you said, error icon and tooltip on hover.